# many2many table for friends system, id's in either column, best schema

Tags: database-design, relational-database

Imagine you have a friends system like facebook.

And you have a m2m table that holds id's for both people the join is between.

Currently, we record the record from either direction. This means the id's could be in either column. So when we do a select we have to search for id's in either column.

We can sort this after the select, by testing against the logged in userId, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this

Comment: _"Currently, we record the record from either direction."_ - does that mean you always store both directions? Or that you store one direction but without any regard as to which user ID is in the first field and which in the second?

Comment: Yeah, we only store in one direction, and then sort it out later on select.

Comment: How do you enforce you don't _also_ store the opposite direction? Do you have something like: `CHECK(FRIEND1_ID < FRIEND2_ID)`?

Comment: We can just store in either direction, and then sort on the way out. I think it doesn't matter, as long as we always look in both directions, and sort if needed.

Comment: So the DBMS won't actually stop you from having 2 rows (with IDs in opposite order) representing the same connection. You should avoid that by using a `CHECK` like described above and a key.

Comment: Ah, within each direction, we also store the type of link. So for example, it could store one link where a friend request is sent, and then the corresponding acceptance, or denial or block could happen from the other direction. To me this is a neat way of storing an activity log between users, but maybe you have a better suggestion? Each action is time stamped, and the most recent record is extracted to determine the current state between users. I would welcome any improvement on this?

Comment: So you **do** differentiate between two directions of the same connection? If so, then it's perfectly fine to have two rows, each representing one of these directions. But (if I understand you correctly) you seem to not guard (in the database constraints) against multiple rows per direction? Do you ensure "request" and "acceptance" always match? Perhaps you should amend your question with the exact description of these connection "types" and versioning.

Comment: I may be missing this, but we would allow for example, to have requests, blocks, acceptance, block, friend, block, request, so it would private a log over time of the requests, Infact by allowing them to be in both directions and resolve later, it allows you to know who made the request, another piece of log information.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find performance is best using a `UNION`:

```
select user_id1 as friend_id
from friends
where user_id2 = ?
union
select user_id2
from friends
where user_id1 = ?
```

And make sure there is an index on both id columns in the association table.